# How to initialize a method in a rake file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, initialization, rake

Apologies for the probably noobie question:

I have a rake task that is designed to take data from a site and save it as a RateData object.

```
rs.each do |market,url| 
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
  doc.xpath("//table/tr").each do |item|  
    provider = "rs"
    market = market
    rate = item.xpath('td[1]').text.gsub!(/[^0-9\.]/, '')
    volume = item.xpath('td[2]').text.gsub(/[^k0-9\.]/, '')
    volume = volume.gsub(/\.(?=.k)/, '')
    volume = volume.gsub(/k/, '00')
    volume = volume.to_f
    rate = rate.to_f
    RateData.create(:provider => provider, :market => market, :rate => rate, :volume => volume, :bid_ask => 1)
  end
end
```

The RateData.create method is in the rate_data_controller and is accessible when I call it in the rails console.  How can I make it available in this rake task?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the environment into the task

```
task :your_task, [] => :environment do
```

or with args

```
task :your_task, [:foo] => :environment do |task, args|
```